# Sharepoint user who can edit content but not site structure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

A bit of a noobie question ...

Just getting to grips with SharePoint 365.  I've created a site with a document library and another site with a list.  The problem I am having is with users.  I haven't fathomed out how to give a user the permission to edit the document library or list content without them also being able to edit the site itself.

I've dropped my library (or list) into a web part on the home page.

Owners of the site can edit the library or list and also edit the site itself.  Members of the site can't edit the site (good) but neither can they edit the content of libraries and lists in the site.

What's the trick I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint there is concept of permissions inheriting. So in default state child inherits permission from its parent.

Site -> List or Library -> Folder (if any) -> Sub folder (if any) -> Item or File

But it is possible to break inheritance in every interface. For list you have to go to list settings and in **Permissions and Management** click on **Permissions for this list**. There you can click on **Stop Inheriting Permissions** and then you can set permission as you like.
There you can return to default state as well, if you stoped inheriting permission.

Answer (score 0):

OOTB there is no permission levels at site level which allows editing of lists/libraries but not the site pages.

Here is how to do so:

1. Break the inheritance at the **Site Pages** library. Access this via **Site Contents** -> **Site Pages**
   [image]
2. On the top right corner, click the *Gear icon*. Choose **Library Settings**,  and **More Library Settings** right after.

[image]

3. Go to **Site Permissions**

[image]

4. Choose **Stop Inheriting Permissions**

[image]

5. Check the *Members* group and select **Edit User Permissions**

[image]

6. Choose **Read** permission rather than **Edit**.

[image]